# Значение символа из ascii таблицы в Python

Tags: python, ascii

Как получить десятичное значение символа из таблицы ascii в Python?
У меня есть буква 'А' русская, я хочу получить 192.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ничего не смог найти, около часа мучаюсь с этим вопросом...

Comment: PS. (классическая) ASCII семибитная кодировка и кода 192 там просто нет. Вы спрашиваете про Windows-1251-

Comment: допустим это так, тогда каким образом все-таки вытащить это заветное число 192 используя букву А?

Answer (score 3):

`ord(ch)` выводит код символа `ch`.

```
a = "А"
b = a.encode('windows-1251') # переводим в Windows-1251
print (ord(b))
```

Обратная операция (вывести символ, используя его численный код) - `chr(num)`:

```
print (chr(192)) # выведет не А, а À, т.к. по умолчанию используется юникод
```

Comment: Наверное стоит отдохнуть, три строки решили все мои проблемы, спасибо огромное!