# Чем является ASCII по отношению к UTF-8 в Python

Tags: python, кодировка

Насколько мне известно - ASCII является надмножеством UTF-8. Что это значит и как это применяется, например для кодировки в Python? Как можно понять, когда необходимо проводить encode/decode, а когда кодировка будет по умолчанию верной? И если Юникод содержит почти символы почти всех языков мира, то в чем преимущество ASCII?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ASCII является надмножеством UTF-8

Наоборот. UTF-8 является надмножеством ASCII (корректнее - ASCII является подмножеством UTF-8).

> Как можно понять, когда необходимо проводить encode/decode

encode/decode откуда куда? Вопрос довольно абстрактный. Если нет явной необходимости (как, например, [в этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/953210/%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-ascii-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B2-python)), то забивать голову перекодировкой текста не нужно.

> то в чем преимущество ASCII?

Ни в чем. Т.к. ASCII - подмножество UTF-8, то текст в кодировке ASCII является также текстом в кодировке UTF-8.